# Generating Thumbnail Image for Android 1.5

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-1.5-cupcake

For API Level 8, to generate thumbnail image we use    Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail.  What should be the approach API Level 3, if one has to generate thumbnail images?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [query functions in Thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#query%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)?